# Why the need to say "solch" instead of "solche"?

Tags: declension

> Was treibt eine **solch** hübsche junge Dame dazu, mit einem Haufen Langweiler herumzuhängen?

All the other words except *solch* (i.e. *eine*, *hübsche*, *junge*) take the feminine accusative form. So I'm not sure why you do not need to say *solche* instead.

Comment: Incidentally, am I correct in assuming that the subject of this sentence is "**was**" and the direct object is "**eine solch hübsche junge Dame**"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Solch" isn't an adjective in this sentence, but an adverb. This is because it serves to precise an adjective (hübsch) and not the nomen (Dame). The sentence would grammmatically be totally valid with "solche", too, but  the meaning would be different, since then "solche" would refer to "Dame".
In English thit difference might be expressed such:

> What brings such a beautiful young lady to... vs.
>
> What brings a beautiful young lady of this kind to...

The difference in meaning isn't negligeable, as you see. ;)

Comment: This is correct, but I am not sure that the English sentences convey the difference.

Comment: Thanks. Incidentally, do you think "**so eine** hübsche junge Dame (wie du)" is the same as "**eine solche** hübsche junge Dame" or "**eine solch** hübsche junge Dame"?

Comment: @Alone-zee yes it is about the same, but I feel solche is stronger, but I may be wrong.